# wireless communication between host and server by using AccessPoint as an intermediate node

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm doing very basic simulations in which I want that a wireless host communicate with server (Standard Host) by using accesspoint as intermediate node. But unfortunately only beacon message is passed to access point and server don't recieve any message.My code is here.

I'll be very thankful for your help.

######--------VFsim.ned-------##########

```
package vf.simulations.simulation;
import inet.linklayer.contract.IWirelessNic;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;
import inet.node.inet.WirelessHost;
import inet.node.wireless.AccessPoint;
import inet.physicallayer.common.packetlevel.RadioMedium;
import inet.physicallayer.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;


//
// TODO documentation
//
network VFsim
{
    @display("bgb=377,307");
    types:
        channel C extends ned.DatarateChannel
        {
            datarate = 100Mbps;
            delay = 0.1us;

        }

    submodules:
        server: StandardHost {
            @display("p=81,85");
        }
        Configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=283,78");
        }
        host: WirelessHost {
            @display("p=276,183");
        }

        accessPoint: AccessPoint {
            @display("p=78,155");
        }
        radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {
            @display("p=282,26");
        }
    connections:
        accessPoint.ethg++ <--> C <--> server.ethg++;
}
```

################---------VFsim.ini--------##############

```
[General]
network = VFsim

**.arp.typename = "GlobalArp"
**.wlan[*].radio.typename = Ieee80211Interface
*.accessPoint.numWlanInterfaces = 1
*.accessPoint.wlan[0].mgmt.ssid = "wlan1"
*.accessPoint.wlan[0].radio.bandName = "5 GHz"
*.accessPoint.app[0].destAddresses = "server"
*.accessPoint.app[0].destPort = 5000

#*.Configurator.config = xmldoc("config.xml")
**.networkLayer.configurator.networkConfiguratorModule = ""

*.host.wlan[*].agent.defaultSsid = "wlan1"
*.host.wlan[*].radio.bandName = "5 GHz"

*.host.numApps = 1
*.host.app[0].typename = "UdpBasicApp"
*.host.app[0].destAddresses = "accessPoint"
*.host.app[0].destPort = 5000
*.host.app[0].messageLength = 1000B
*.host.app[0].sendInterval = exponential(12ms)
*.host.app[0].packetName = "UDPData"

*.server.numApps = 1
*.server.app[0].typename = "UdpSink"
*.server.app[0].localPort = 5000
*.server.app[0].destAddresses = "accessPoint"


**.wlan[*].mac.useAck = false
**.wlan[*].mac.fullDuplex = false
**.radio.transmitter.power = 3.5mW
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.communicationRange = 500m
**.wlan[*].radio.receiver.ignoreInterference = true
**.wlan[*].mac.headerLength = 23B

**.bitrate = 1Mbps
```

Answer (score 0):

For `host` set `server` as destination for the UDP traffic. In your ini file set:

```
*.host.app[0].destAddresses = "server"
```

**EDIT**
The instance of `IPv4NetworkConfigurator` must have the name `configurator`, not `Configurator`. Therefore in `VFsim.ned` change into:

```
configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator
```

Moreover, remove this line from ini:

```
**.networkLayer.configurator.networkConfiguratorModule = ""
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did this but I did not achieve my goal. I commented my accessPoint configuration area and changed according to your answer by setting local and destination addresses.

Comment: I deleted my lines after your edit section, but I can't achieve my goal. "Associated with AP" blinks at the host but can't send messages to host.

Comment: *but can't send message to server